# JQuery not changing the content of div from even numbered links?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Thanks for taking the time to look at this post.

So I have managed to do my task to a point.
I am pulling data from a database called posts with the following fields: `id, account_name, data, heading, subheading, videos, voice_notes, music, images, post_date, date_for_post`.

So This is the process:
1 - Pull data from db and put into array
2 - Make unordered list from array with links
3 - when link is clicked, fill content div with that posts data.

Now it will load the specific posts data on odd numbered links, but on even numbered links it wont load the data into the container? using the same method? I have re-ordered the lists and still, even numbered list items just wont work. Am I doing something wrong?

I have also tried putting in a blank list item in between the posts to see if it were the list items themselves that were not calling the function, but it seems that it is only the even links.

I don't know how else to explain it, here is my code:

```
<?php
$connection=mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());} 
// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbname', $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
} 

$query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if(!$result){
    die('Invalid query' . mysql_error());
}

$posts = array();
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $posts[] = $line;
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/content.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">some data</div>

<div id="links">
    <ul>
    <?php
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $data =  "'".$post['data']."'";
            echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="getContent(\'#content\', '. $data .');">'. $post['date_for_post'] .'</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

and the getContent function:

```
function getContent(element, data){
$(element).text(data);
}
```

I cannot figure out why. here is a graphical representation of whats happening:
[image: page loads]
[image: first link pressed, post loads]
[image: second link is pressed, post id not loaded]
[image: third link is pressed, post is loaded]
[image: fourth link is pressed, post is not loaded]
[image: see, there are posts in the database]

I have tried inserting black list items to see if it was the actual even list items not calling the function, but it is the even list items with the content inside that wont work, if that makes sense?

Please help as I have no clue what is going on and how to fix it.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

it seems to be that the longer posts dont display, the shorter do. I have the data type in the database set to text, not varchar. So where is the issue with size? Is there a maximum size I am allowed to put through the JQuery function? Or in the database? Because it shows in the database, but not on the post

Comment: Try it like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/8m593/

Comment: if you inspect your page once its loaded, are your even links empty or are they feeded ? Is there any error in the debug tool when you click on those links.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with quotes and double quotes here in your code:

```
$data =  "'".$post['data']."'";
echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="getContent(\'#content\', '. $data .');">'.$post['date_for_post'] .'</a></li>';
```

Check the source of generated HTML page. There should be incorrect 'li' tags. I suggest change your code to this:

```
$data =  $post['data'];
echo '<li><a href="#" onclick="getContent(\'#content\', \''. $data .'\');">'.$post['date_for_post'] .'</a></li>';
```

Hope it helps.

Also, check if the quotes in text from database are causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what's going on, try to provide a jsfiddle.  Even though you are using php, you can create a manual feed of json data and test out the javascript.  To make it less confusing, have the data stored in a ...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dbObj = <?php $post ?>  // $post object to be formatted in json
        var render;
        for (obj in dbObj) {
            render = render + '<li><a href="#" onclick=getContent("#content", ' + obj.data + '");>' +obj.date+ '</a></li>'
        $('#links ul').append(render);
    });
</script>
```

If that works and you really want to have the php print out the list, then you can replace it with the php foreach; these days, developers are allowing the client-side to render templates/html and at least you'll know the js works this way! :-)

```
   <?php
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            echo '<li><a href="#" onclick=getContent("#content", "'. $post["data"] .'");>'. $post['date_for_post'] .'</a></li>';
        }
    ?>
```